# What are the better WYSIWYG post editor replacement alternatives?

Tags: wysiwyg, visual-editor, post-editor

I hate the built-in WYSWIG editor for WordPress. (EDIT: Editors of the sites I support hate it, which in turn makes more work for me. Hence, I hate it.) I know there are some alternatives out there, but I'm curious what the more functional and usable ones are?

Issues that I hear:

- The text auto formatting either a)
  adds html or b) strips html. This is
  annoying.
- The view within the preview section
  doesn't use the stylesheets of the
  web site itself, so it's not really
  WYSIWYG

Comment: What about it do you hate?

Comment: I shouldn't say hate. I use the html editor. What I hate is that I have to support a team of people who hate the editor :p

Comment: More specifically what attributes about it do they hate? Replacing it with one having those same attributes would be a waste. Maybe update your question with more details?

Comment: You know you can fix the second issue: http://www.wdmac.com/how-to-use-custom-styles-in-the-word-press-post-editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when one of my clients have doesn't like the TinyMCE editor i add the [Dean's FCKEditor For WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fckeditor-for-wordpress-plugin/) plugin that integrates the ckeditor and install the office 2003 skin for it so they find it easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use client blogging tools such as

- [Windows Live Writer](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer)
- [Mars Edit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/)

This might get round their objections - Live Writer can definitely preview using site stylesheets